# XAML KeyBinding 1,2,3

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, keyboard

I decided to duplicate the buttons by pressing the keys on my page but getting an error like this:

"1" can not be used as a value for "Key". Numbers are not valid enumeration values.

```
 <Page.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Btn_Click}" 
               CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=btn1,Path=Content}"
                Key="1"/>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Btn_Click}" 
               CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=btn2,Path=Content}"
                Key="2"/>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Btn_Click}" 
               CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=btn3,Path=Content}"
                Key="3"/>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Btn_Click}" 
               CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=btn4,Path=Content}"
                Key="4"/>
</Page.InputBindings>
```

Can I deceive the system?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `D1`, which is the enum value for the `1` key. See the [Key Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.key(v=vs.110).aspx) page for a list of all possible values.

```
<KeyBinding Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" Key="D1"/>
```

or just biniding:

```
<KeyBinding Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" Key="{Binding MyKey}"/>
```

VM:

```
public Key MyKey
{
    get => Key.D1;
}
```

this is because you can't do enumerator like:

```
enum MyEnum
{
    1,
    2,
    3
};
```

Comment: I think, you mentioned to comment post not my anwser :d

Comment: It was only an extra information since they Key property is an enum